# Connect outbound call to a lync conference

Tags: sip, lync, ucma, conference

Is it possible to, given a UCMA application (using application or user end points), to create an outbound sip call and then join this call to an active audio conference on lync server?

If so, how would I do that?

I know one can create an outbound call and also I know it's possible to join an endpoint to an active conference, but has anyone done this two things at the same time?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're creating a new `Conversation`  with your UCMA application (instead of getting an incoming call to your app), you can connect this new conversation to a conference.

The trick to to use the conversation's `ConferenceSession` object to join the conference, rather than calling to it directly, and then establishing the call without a target uri.

Note that you need to impersonate the conversation if you attempt to make multiple calls to the same conference from the same application endpoint.

For reference of the `BeginJoin`, see this MSDN page: [ConferenceSession.BeginJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.conferencesession.beginjoin_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx).

```
var conversation = new Conversation( <your application endpoint> );
conversation.ConferenceSession.BeginJoin("<your conference uri>", (joinresult) => {
    conversation.ConferenceSession.EndJoin(joinresult);

    // User has joined conference here.

    var call = new AudioVideoCall(conversation);
    call.BeginEstablish(new AudioVideoCallEstablishOptions(), (establishresult) => {
        call.EndEstablish(establishresult);

        // Call is established with conference now.

    });
});
```